# Receive used language when using google Speech To Text API in conjunction with "alternativeLanguageCodes"

Tags: google-cloud-platform

So I run a speech transcription and supply some `alternativeLanguageCodes` in addition to the main `languageCode`

for Example:

```
languageCode: "en"
alternativeLanguageCodes: ["fr","it"]
```

Google speech automatically returns me the one transcription where the confidence is high enough that it might actually be the right one that the audio file's speaker speaks in. Great!

But ... I want to also know which language(code) it actually is/used. Is there any way to make the api return such metadata (like lang: 'fr') for that result alternative?

Comment: Programming questions should be asked on [so].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The v1 version of Speech API does not provide the language code that recognized from your audio (which I think is the one you are using). However, the "v1p1beta1" version of the Google Cloud Speech API returns the Language code that recognized from your audio, check the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1p1beta1/speech/recognize#speechrecognitionresult) about the response returned by the API. So, I recommend to use that version.